# What is this strange valve/trap from my boiler to condensate pump?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, pump, condensate

I have a condensate pump attached to a valiant combi boiler with the usual pvc pipe turning into it (removed in picture, but works fine going into the point behind the copper pipe here), with the also normal outflow clear pipe also working fine.

Yet I have also this strange (and heavily crystallised) piece running into it from what I think is the overflow pipe of the boiler. What is it? A steam trap? Does it need replacing? Feel like I've googled everything and can't even find something remotely like it.[image]

Comment: It looks like 1/2 that elbow is _missing_ and you're worried about the mineral build up on the outside? Maybe include some pics showing an overall view and where that pipe leads off to.

Comment: See answer, seems to be a piece called a Tundish specifically for the pressure overflow pipe and the missing sections are part of the design. Took it off and cleaned up seems in correct condition/use.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that cast iron piece is called an "air gap" which is used so contaminated water of a sewer pipe or drain  will never be drawn up that discharge pipe to contaminate anything above. This is usually how  water cooler is drained so the discharge of water to the drain or sewer discharge pipe could never cause a negative pressure on the drain and pull water up onto the water cooler surface. Google the words "air gap"

Comment: Yeah, interesting in this spot seems to serve a dual purpose as both an air gap and also a way to prevent hot steam from a pressure overflow melting the plastic pump. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Found it, is a piece called a [Tundish](https://www.viessmann.co.uk/heating-advice/what-is-a-tundish).

Comment: Can't say fairer than that.